# How to find average and use group by at same time in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have these tables:

```
Student(Rollno,name,address)
Subject(sub_code,sub_name)
Marks(Rollno,sub_code, marks)
```

I want to display average of marks roll no wise with name too. I used this query to find average of marks:

```
SELECT Rollno,avg(marks) FROM MARKS GROUP BY Rollno;
```

How do I get name of respective roll numbers ?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 2):

Try using a join:

```
SELECT M.Rollno, S.NAME, avg(M.marks) 
FROM Marks AS M  
JOIN Students AS S ON M.rollno = S.rollno 
GROUP BY M.Rollno, S.NAME,;
```